# How vs the way vs What

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, sentence

I know 'How' can be replaced with 'the way'  in the sentence.
So, I've brought some sentences confusing me.

(I was talking about some policy the government would implement later on. And all of sudden, 3 replies came across my mind.)

1. this is how other countries do
2. this is the way other countries do
3. this is what other countries do

I guess number 3 makes sense, and number 1 doesn't because it doesn't have an object. Number 2 would be wrong as well since how and the way would work in the same way. And then, what if I use the verb 'use' in the number 2?

ex) this is the way other countries use, which is correct grammatically because the way can be a noun. However, number 1 (this is how other countries use.) is not applied.

this is all I've been thinking so far. Am I correct??

Comment: _How_ and _the way_ are interchangeable, because _how_ is the relative pronoun (or adverb, if you prefer) that requires _way_ as its antecedent, just as _why_ requires _reason_ as its antecedent. Both are very limited in distribution and meaning. _How_ is more restricted than _why_, however. You can say _the reason he did it, why he did it,_ and _the reason why he did it_; but you can only say _the way he did it_ and _how he did it_. *_The way how he did it_ is ungrammatical, because _how_ simply can't be used as a normal relative pronoun with an antecedent.

Comment: You can't use the word _use_ in example 2.

Answer (score 1):

This is how other countries do..................(something)

This is the way other countries do...............(something)

This is what other countries do.  (nothing to add because it stands alone as a statement)

This is the way other countries use.....................(something)